# In drupal webform, %email_values are sent ,but I want field key values instead of it

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

for example,in the following component,

---

label:select your favorite area

1|asia
2|africa

---

I have e-mail notification as following.

"select your favorite area" "asia"

but i want to have just like following format.

"select your favorite area" "1

Please show me How can i do it.